# Partition function of particles having magnetic moment $\mu$ placed in a magnetic field $B$. (Particles obey Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics.)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

How to calculate partition function in this case? Like, here we get two discrete energy levels $uB$ and $-uB$ but particles obey MB statistics. So we can't use integration formula of partition function that has exponential(-Beta*Hamiltonian). (Also i am confused in Statistics, like what is there significance (role in distribution if energy levels are discrete).

Comment: Classical magnetic moments in an external field have a continuum of possible energies $\mu B cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between dipole moment and field.

Comment: Which integration formula? If you assume just two states, then partition function is a sum of two terms.

Comment: Classical one which use exp(-bE)dqdp to find partition function of classical gas